# Set Price and Min Order quantity in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-hook, wpallimport

I have just very nearly completed a custom theme for a client of mine. However he wants to set the price of 0.50eur and a minimum order price for these products [here](https://jatsmobiles.uk/product-category/ppe/)

The problem I have is that all products are being imported from an eternal site using WP All Import Pro. I have 2 feeds running, 1 that brings in the products 4 times a day and one that updates the prices every hour.

Obviously there is some sort of filter I need to add to my functions.php file but where to start on this I have no idea. Many thanks for any help.

Comment: Sorry but i can't get what you are trying to achieve. Are you trying to hook into wp all import? or your feeds run with some external plugin/scripts that is taking care of updating stuff on your website? I guess we need more info to point you in the right direction, there are a lot of possibilities but you need to be more clear for your goal

Comment: Hi Diego, So basically wp all import brings in multiple products, images, tiles and woocommerce categories on the one feed 4 times a day. I have another feed that imports and updates the prices every hour for those said products. What my client wants is the set the price to .50eur for all products under 1 specific product category and set the min order to 500pcs. Hope that makes sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comments i guess you would need to take a look at this first [from Wp All Import documentation](https://www.wpallimport.com/documentation/advanced/action-reference/)

After that you can see you have multiple hooks, one of them is pmxi_saved_post, going on with the example you could do something like:

```
function fix_price_after_import( $post_id, $xml_node, $is_update ) {
    if ( ! empty( $post_id ) ) {
        $current_prod = wc_get_product( $post_id );
        if ( ! empty( $current_prod ) && $current_prod instanceof WC_Product ) {
            $categories_to_update = array(100,200); // product_cat IDS
            if (!empty(array_intersect($categories_to_update,$current_prod->get_category_ids()))){
                // Current prod has at least one of the categories you have to update
                $current_prod->set_price(0.5);  
                $current_prod->save();
            }
        }
    }
    
}

add_action( 'pmxi_saved_post', 'fix_price_after_import', 10, 3 );
```

I didn't test the code but it should give you a starting point

Comment: Thank you for that Diego, have added it to my functions.php file, nothing updated as yet though am afraid.

Comment: Do you have any way to debug that? if that code is ever run? do you have a staging? if so maybe u can go step-by-step from that example removing the "ifs" and see if anything works / the code execute at all